# C++ Unity Plugin how to release USB audio device

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine

I've created a C++ Unity plugin that sends audio to a speaker via USB.
Everything works fine the first time I hit play on Unity, however, after the first playback if I hit play once more then unity crashes. In addition, I have to occasionally reset my computer to get the plugin working.

I'm thinking that I need to add the proper command to my "OnDestroy" function in my .CS Unity marshaling script. Here's what I have right now...

```
private void OnDestroy()
{
    Audio.stop_sound();
    Debug.Log("stop called");
}
```

stop_sound is a simple function that exhibits a stop to the callback.
Any ideas?

Comment: This is not nearly enough information to even venture a reasonable guess as to the root of the problem. What is your plugin doing? Is it statically linked or dynamically loaded? What resources is the plugin allocating internally? What version of Unity? Have you attached the VS debugger to see what's happening in your plugin? Have you looked at the Unity plugin life cycle? What do you see in your logs and the Unity logs? Have you checked for memory or resource leaks? ... etc ad infinitum

Comment: in your C++ don't forget to free any native handles you might have created, and Release any COM objects you might have AddReffed